# Capybara Acceptance Tests: undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, acceptance-testing

I'm in the process of upgrading an old krufty application to Rails 3.1.  The company has been using RSpec and Capybara for acceptance tests.  We've got some acceptance tests under `spec/acceptance` that are failing with the following message:

```
Failure/Error: get @url
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007feb7c0abf58>
```

Here's an example of one of the tests (from the top of the file):

```
require_relative 'acceptance_helper'                                                                                                                                                 

feature 'Catalog' do                                                                                                                                                                 
  before do                                                                                                                                                                          
    Settings.use_catalog_navigation = true                                                                                                                                           
  end                                                                                                                                                                                

  context 'with a Vendor' do                                                                                                                                                         
    before do                                                                                                                                                                        
      @vendor = create(:vendor, slug: 'abc')                                                                                                                                         
      @product = create(:product_with_variants, vendor: @vendor)                                                                                                                     

      @non_vendor_product = create(:product_with_variants)                                                                                                                           
      @invisible_product = create(:product_with_variants,                                                                                                                            
                                   vendor: @vendor,                                                                                                                                  
                                   visible: false)                                                                                                                                   
      @non_available_product = create(:product_with_variants,                                                                                                                        
                                       vendor: @vendor,                                                                                                                              
                                       available: false)                                                                                                                             

      @url = "/#{@vendor.slug}"                                                                                                                                                      
    end                                                                                                                                                                              

    it 'sets @vendor' do   # <- FIRST FAILING TEST                                                                                                                                                          
      get @url                                                                                                                                                                       
      assigns(:vendor).should == @vendor                                                                                                                                             
    end

    ...
```

When consulting the oracle, I keep stumbling across issues mentioning the 'visit' method such as this:  https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/814

I also keep coming across posts related to this article:  http://alindeman.github.com/2012/11/11/rspec-rails-and-capybara-2.0-what-you-need-to-know.html

I'm not sure that I'm having the same issue.  I can post my `spec_helper.rb` and `acceptance_helper.rb` if they will be of any use.

I guess it's worth noting that these specs passed before I updated rspec-rails and capybara.

My gut feeling is that perhaps rspec-rails is clobbering some of capybara's methods, or some of capybara's methods are simply no longer being loaded.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: I had a similar problem recently when upgrading from Rails 3.1.0 to 3.1.10. The answer (for me) was to downgrade my selenium-webdriver to 2.21.1 from 2.21.2. Give this a shot and hopefully it helps move you closer to solving your problem!

Comment: We weren't using selenium.  It turns out the problem was that there were two test blocks in the Gemfile, which I believe was causing RSpec to be loaded after Capybara.  I'd answer my own question, but I'm not 100% certain why having two test blocks was causing the issue.  I'll need to track down the person responsible and ask why it was done that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try and add `config.include Capybara::DSL` in `spec_helper.rb`, inside the config block. like so:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
```